# Unable to find element using Xpath and CSS

Tags: java, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am unable to find Element using XPATH and CSS

Using firefox i am executing the code, i have tried every method for finding the element mentioned here but always i get the error mentioned below.

> 1500539792269 geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.18.0
>   1500539792279 geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:18947
>   1500539793062 geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"]
>   1500539798479 Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 64608 Jul 20, 2017
>   2:06:39 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Detected dialect: W3C JavaScript warning:
>   https://login-qa.ihg.com/forms/iam/responsiveV3/js/jquery.min.js, line
>   1: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use
>   //# instead Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
>   sidebar-button For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html Build info:
>   version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'

Code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("sidebar-button")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='reservations']/a"));
action.moveToElement(we).build().perform();
```

Please help me out in resolving this problem

Comment: Please share HTML snippet.

Comment: it seems like there is some problem with geckdriver, do you get this error with other browser or other firefox or geck version. could you please check?

Answer (score 0):

Give some wait time before  `driver.findElement(By.id("sidebar-button")).click();`

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(
    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("sidebar-button")));
```

as you got 'NoSuchElementException' for first line